# Virtual Serial Port on linux through TCP

Tags: linux, tcp, serial-port, hardware, virtual-serial-port

With the Virtual Serial Ports Emulator I can

- Create a virtual serial port connector
- Choose a port e.g. COM35 for the connector
- Create TCP-Server
- Assign the previously created virtual serial port to the server

[image]

Then clients can establish a stream connection to the tcp server by knowing the ip address, tcp port and the name of the virtual serial port.

In the above example I created an MICRO_Test application (c++) that simply connects to virtual serial port. When I write data to this port it will be received by all clients.

You can see it in the log in the image above.

---

While this is on windows, **is there a way to achieve some equivalent behaviour on linux machines?**

To sum up:

```
Some binary code (as interface for e.g. webservices)
                    |
                    |
                    | [send/receive via virtual com port]
                    |
                    |
TCP Server & COM connector (multiple instances possible with different ports)
       |          |          |
       |          |          |
       |          |          |
    Client 1   Client 2   Client X
```

The clients read physical data from their real com ports and send the data through the tcp stream to the server.

For linux I read a lot about socat, tty and ser2net. However I cannot get a real clue how to achieve an architecture like above on linux? Can you help me out with some information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you could use Python with [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) package. It can handle COM ports, RFC2217 (`ser2net`) and TCP raw connections (`socat`).

For example you would start `socat` on all clients with real hardware and connect to them via Python script.

This statement opens raw socket:

```
tcp_con = serial.serial_for_url('socket://<my_ip>:<my_port>')
```